# getting the current index of the clicked item in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of images

```
var moniqueThumbs = document.getElementsByClassName('moniqueThumbs');
```

Now i use click function to select the clicked element.

```
for (var i = 0; i < moniqueThumbs.length; i++) {

    moniqueThumbs[i].addEventListener("click", grabBigImgPath); 
}
```

**Now how can save the current Index of the clicked item??**

```
function grabBigImgPath() {
var currentItemclicked=this;
}
```

**I mean save the index of currentItemclicked???**

Comment: You'll need `closure` in the `for` loop

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like

```js
var moniqueThumbs = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('moniqueThumbs')); //using the slice to convert the HTMLCollection to a real array

for (var i = 0; i < moniqueThumbs.length; i++) {

  moniqueThumbs[i].addEventListener("click", grabBigImgPath);
}

function grabBigImgPath() {
  var index = moniqueThumbs.indexOf(this)
    //then use the Array.indexOf() to get the index
  snippet.log('clicked: ' + index)
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<div class="moniqueThumbs">1</div>
<div class="moniqueThumbs">2</div>
<div class="moniqueThumbs">3</div>
<div class="moniqueThumbs">4</div>
<div class="moniqueThumbs">5</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass as an argument:

```
for (var i = 0; i < moniqueThumbs.length; i++) {
   moniqueThumbs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      grabBigImgPath(i);
   }); 
 }

function grabBigImgPath(index) {
   var currentItemclicked=index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For concise, clear code that runs on modern browsers (with polyfills available for dumb browsers)

```
moniqueThumbs.forEach(function(thumb, indx) {
    thumb.addEventListener('click', grabBigImgPath.bind(thumb, indx));
});
```

[forEach polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill)

[bind polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill)